# What information is located on the clipboard? Using Python 3, win32clipboard

Tags: python, clipboard

Recently I wanted to write something like a synchronized clipboard. So i wrote this code on **python 3 using win32clipboard from pywin32** to see what is located on clipboard.

'''

```
import win32clipboard as wn

def get_buffer():
    data = {}
    wn.OpenClipboard()
    next_format = wn.EnumClipboardFormats(0)
    while next_format:
        try:
            data[next_format] = wn.GetClipboardData(next_format)
        except:
            print("LOSE FORMAT", next_format)
        next_format = wn.EnumClipboardFormats(next_format)
    wn.CloseClipboard()
    return data

data = get_buffer()
for now_format in data:
    print(now_format, type(data[now_format]), data[now_format])
```

For example if you copy just text: **"Hello world" from notepad**, then you get this:

```
13 <class 'str'> Hello world
16 <class 'bytes'> b'\t\x04\x00\x00'
1 <class 'bytes'> b'Hello world'
7 <class 'bytes'> b'Hello world'
```

But when you tried something more complex, like copy **file from your desktop**, you get this:

```
LOSE FORMAT 49326
49161 <class 'bytes'> b'"\x02 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
49470 <class 'bytes'> b"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\...
49672 <class 'bytes'> b'\x7f\x00D w\x00@\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
49673 <class 'bytes'> b'0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
49490 <class 'bytes'> b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x...
15 <class 'tuple'> ('C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\Unity Hub.lnk',)
49158 <class 'bytes'> b'C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\UNITYH~1.LNK\x00'
49159 <class 'bytes'> b'C\x00:\x00\\\x00U\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00\\\x00P\x00u\x00b...
49366 <class 'bytes'> b'\x01\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
49493 <class 'bytes'> b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
49471 <class 'bytes'> b'\xe5\x01\x00\x00o\x03\x00\x00\xe8\xff\xff\xff\xe0\xff\xff\...
49476 <class 'bytes'> b'\x05\x00\x00\x00'
49492 <class 'bytes'> b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
49171 <class 'bytes'> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00...
```

or something like copy **images from paint**:

```
LOSE FORMAT 3
49161 <class 'bytes'> b'\xaa\nn\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
49163 <class 'bytes'> b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x...
49156 <class 'bytes'> b'BM\x06\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x...
49155 <class 'bytes'> b'Paint.Picture\x00\xc8\xe7\xee\xe1\xf0\xe0\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\...
49166 <class 'bytes'> b'\x90\x00\x00\x00!K\xe3\xd3u\x9d\x1a\x10\x8c=\x00\xaa\x00\x...
8 <class 'bytes'> b'(\x00\x00\x00\xb7\x00\x00\x00\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\...
49171 <class 'bytes'> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x...
14 <class 'bytes'> b'\x01\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
2 <class 'int'> -821748004
17 <class 'bytes'> b'|\x00\x00\x00\xb7\x00\x00\x00\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\...
```

What does this huge amount of information mean? Why am I losing information?
Can somebody explain why so many things are copied and what it all means?
Where i can find information about formats that are using on clipboard?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Why clipboard contained not information not in one but in many formats? for what reason?

Comment: and i didn't find anything about formats 49161, 49163, 49171 and others

Comment: I've written some more detail out in an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats#standard-clipboard-formats), there are three classes of clipboard formats: Standard formats, registered formats, and private formats.

[Standard formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) are things like text or images that are defined by the system for any program to use. In your example, format 3 is defined to be `CF_METAFILEPICT`.

> Handle to a metafile picture format as defined by the [METAFILEPICT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-metafilepict) structure. When passing a CF_METAFILEPICT handle by means of DDE, the application responsible for deleting hMem should also free the metafile referred to by the CF_METAFILEPICT handle.

[Registered formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclipboardformata) are formats that specific programs register for their own needs. These use values in the range `0xC000` through `0xFFFF`. In decimal, that's 49152 to 65535. So you'll have to consult the documentation for the particular programs to see what those are and how they're meant to be read.

[Private formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats#private-clipboard-formats) are for private use internal to particular applications. These use values from `0x0200` to `0x02FF` (512 to 767). None of your examples are in this range, so I assume you haven't encountered it.